# Anaconda 3 won't load BLAS library on Windows 10 unless ran in administrator mode

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, theano, blas

I'm using Widows 10 64 bit, running conda 4.8.3, python 3.7.7, and mingw64
(gcc version 5.3.0).  I updated all packages using

```
conda update --all -y
```

and then installed theano version 1.0.4 using

```
conda install theano -y
```

Now

```
import theano
```

gives

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions
```

Starting anaconda3 in administrator mode, however, and running

```
import theano
```

produces no such warning.  Why aren't BLAS DLLs getting loaded when I run anaconda3 in user mode? Everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: I found a temporary workaround: edit the file c:\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py and replace StrParam(default_blas_ldflags), with StrParam('-L"C:\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin" -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lmkl_rt'), Then "import theano" works fine in user mode and theano works fast.